# How to write mapreduce for this scenario?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

## This is Data Set

> UserId, Category Id, date
>
> A,123, 2016-01-01
>  A,123, 2016-01-01
>  B,123, 2016-01-01
>   C,123, 2016-01-01
>  C,123, 2016-01-01
>  D,123, 2016-01-01
>   E,123, 2016-01-01

## Need the output as below:

> Day, Category Id, Frequency of views, No of users
>
> 2016-01-01, 123, 1, 3
>   2016-01-01, 123, 2, 2

## Explanation:

As per the data set, there are 3 users (B, D, E) viewed the category just once. 
There are 2 users (A, C) viewed the category 2 times.

The hive query for this scenario is:

select numberOfUsers, category, impression_date, count(numberOfUsers) as    countOfUsers from (   select count(user_id) as numberOfUsers, category, impression_date from userVisit
    group by category, user_id, impression_date) temp
    group by numberOfUsers, category, impression_date
    sort by countOfUsers asc;

What will be the Mapreduce code for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using nested query, it makes sense that you might have to run MapReduce (chain) twice on the data-set to get the required result.

I would suggest the following as an approach.

Step 1. Read the text and take full row of text as Key and perform Word count (can be better said as Row Count as full row is out key)

**Map 1 Output-**

Key         ~       Value
A,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
A,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
B,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
C,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
C,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
D,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
E,123,2016-01-01 ~  1

**Reduce 1 Output-**

Key            ~        Value
A,123,2016-01-01 ~  2
B,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
C,123,2016-01-01 ~  2
D,123,2016-01-01 ~  1
E,123,2016-01-01 ~  1

Step 2. Now take this output as input to next MapReduce and perform the word count on this row. Ofcourse you will have to rearrage and modify your input key according to the output you want.

-Read both key and value form previos output as a record

-Rearrange this record in format as "A,2016-01-01,123 2"

-remove the first charater and ',' and use the rest of record as key in word (row) count


**Map 2 output--**



Key             ~   Value 
2016-01-01,123 2 ~  1
2016-01-01,123 1 ~  1
2016-01-01,123 2 ~  1   
2016-01-01,123 1 ~  1
2016-01-01,123 1 ~  1

**Reduce 2 output--**



Key             ~   Value 
2016-01-01,123 1 ~3
2016-01-01,123 2 ~2

Comment: Example of chaining jobs is [link](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/chaining-jobs-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html)